# How to show url in Magento2?

Tags: product, magento2.2, grid, uicomponent, php-7

I have created custom admin grid which contains column name **sku**.

How to make this sku field value into url.That url go for product edit page.

**In layout file**

```
 <column name="product_sku" class="Xxx\Stock\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Product">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>                   
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Sku</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
```

**Product.php**

```
 public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            $fieldName = $this->getData('name');
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                if (isset($item[$fieldName])) {
                    $html = "<a href='" . $this->context->getUrl('adminhtml/catalog_product/edit',['id'=>$item[$fieldName]]) . "'>";
                    $html .= __('Product Page');
                    $html .= "</a>";
                    $item[$fieldName] = $html;
                }
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
```

Its not working....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL should be specified as **'catalog/product/edit'** and not 'adminhtml/catalog_product/edit'

To get product id from product sku, make below changes in class -

> Xxx\Stock\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Product

```
public function __construct(\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory, ...)
{
    ...
    $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
    $this->product = $this->productFactory->create();
}
public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            $fieldName = $this->getData('name');
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                if (isset($item[$fieldName])) {
                   $productId = $this->product->getIdBySku($item[$fieldName]);
                    $html = "<a href='" . $this->context->getUrl('catalog_product/edit',['id'=>$productId]) . "'>";
                    $html .= __('Product Page');
                    $html .= "</a>";
                    $item[$fieldName] = $html;
                }
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
```

Furthermore, you will need to specify that the column is HTML otherwise it will print out the HTML of the link itself instead of creating a link. This is done using the bodyTmpl as in this example

```
<column name="myColumn">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Column</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

Comment: Did my solution work for you?

Comment: Yes ...I'm get the link without html tag.But if I'm clicking that link...It not go for desire page.........

Comment: so on which page its redirecting you?

Comment: The link go for product edit page when i click the 'open link to new tab'..

Comment: Debug the code and check the value of the id which you are passing. As seen from your code $item[$fieldName] should return the correct value which you have retrieved for that column field

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74803/discussion-between-shireen-n-and-priya-m).

Comment: @ShireenN  how to make a link open in new widow for this custom column on the grid